# Create pandas dataframe from list of dictionary of list

Tags: python, pandas

How can I create a dataframe from a list of dictionaries that contain list of rows for each key?
Please check example below:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> rec_set1 = {'col1': [1,2,3], 'col2': [5,3,4], 'col3': ['x','y','z']}
>>> rec_set2 = {'col1': [5,6,7], 'col2': [-4,6,2], 'col3': ['p','q','r']}
>>> rec_set_all = [rec_set1, rec_set2]
>>> df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(rec_set1)
>>> df
   col1  col2 col3
0     1     5    x
1     2     3    y
2     3     4    z
```

All good so far.
Now I try to append rec_set2 and this is what happens:

```
>>> df = df.append(rec_set2, ignore_index=True)
>>> df
        col1        col2       col3
0          1           5          x
1          2           3          y
2          3           4          z
3  [5, 6, 7]  [-4, 6, 2]  [p, q, r]
```

1. Not what I was expecting. What append function should I use ?
2. And rather than doing it in a loop, is there a simple one-line way to create the entire dataframe from `rec_set_all` ?

Comment: `pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(rec_set1), pd.DataFrame(rec_set2)])`?

Comment: wouldn't this `df = df.append(pd.DataFrame(rec_set2), ignore_index=True)` work? as in you just forgot to turn the other dictionary into a dataframe?

Comment: _Not what I was expecting._ Really? Have you looked at the docs for `.append()`?

Comment: I forgot to add: Where is this data coming from? Odds are we can avoid this issue entirely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are starting out with a list of dictionaries of lists, you can start by using list comprehension to turn it into a list of DataFrames:

```
rec_set1 = {'col1': [1,2,3], 'col2': [5,3,4], 'col3': ['x','y','z']}
rec_set2 = {'col1': [5,6,7], 'col2': [-4,6,2], 'col3': ['p','q','r']}
... (etc.)
rec_setn = {...}
rec_set_all = [rec_set1, rec_set2,...,rec_setn]

df_list = [pd.DataFrame(r) for r in rec_set_all]
```

Next, you can use the simple `pd.concat` method do combine it all into one DataFrame:

```
df_all = pd.concat(df_list)
```

If you want to reset the indexes so that it is coninuous rather than 0,1,2,0,1,2,etc., you can use this to renumber them all from 0:

```
df.reset_index(inplace=True,drop=True)
```

The result from your example would be:

```
    col1 col2 col3
0    1    5     x
1    2    3     y
2    3    4     z
3    5   -4     p
4    6    6     q
5    7    2     r
```

#### Edit

Including info from the comment from AMC, it can be written as a one-liner:

```
df = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(r) for r in rec_set_all], ignore_index = True)
```

Comment: `pandas.concat()` has an `ignore_index` parameter, so you can probably avoid having to do the `.reset_index()`.

Comment: It might be more efficient to use a generator expression instead: `df = pd.concat((pd.DataFrame(r) for r in rec_set_all), ignore_index = True)`

Comment: `df = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(r) for r in rec_set_all], ignore_index = True)` works perfectly ! Although it looks like there is no simple `pd.DataFrame(rec_set_all)` type of call that does the iteration internally for you.

Comment: @deeSo How did you end up in this situation? Surely there has to a be a better way of doing things, no?

Comment: @AMC I used a simple example to provide clarity. I am actually working on a larger data set - multiple input files each having json in the format described in rec_set1

Answer (score 0):

This will also work. Just append the new dict as a DataFrame.

```
rec_set1 = {'col1': [1,2,3], 'col2': [5,3,4], 'col3': ['x','y','z']}
rec_set2 = {'col1': [5,6,7], 'col2': [-4,6,2], 'col3': ['p','q','r']}
rec_set_all = [rec_set1, rec_set2]
df = pd.DataFrame(rec_set1)

# append as rec_set2 as a DataFrame
df.append(pd.DataFrame(rec_set2))
```

Comment: It's better to concatenate than to append repeatedly.